# JNativeHook (GlobalScreen) Not Working with switch and if Statements

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a simple tool for retrieving the current mouse coordinates to help me code future projects. I've decided not to download one, as I would like to expand my knowledge as a self-taught programmer.

I'm using JNativeHook as a library in NetBeans to help me with KeyListeners when the JFrame is not focused. I've researched and debugged for a few hours, and have figured out that the KeyReleased method won't work with if and switch statements. It detects the KeyRelease, as I put `System.out.println();` in the method; it printed it out. My code is down below.

```
package Main;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.dispatcher.SwingDispatchService;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class MainClass implements NativeKeyListener {

    static JFrame frame;
    static JLabel label;
    static JPanel panel;
    static boolean run = true; //pause variable

    private static void jframe(){ //JFrame code
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse Coordinates");    
        label = new JLabel();
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static void check(){ //updating label text
        if(run){ //if not paused
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(run){ //loop
                        label.setText(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().toString().replaceAll("java.awt.Point", "")); 
                        frame.setSize(label.getWidth() + 5, label.getHeight() + 5); //Adapt frame size to fit label
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case 27: //close code (esc key)
                System.exit(0);
            case 80: //pause code (p key)
                run = !run;
                check();
            case 67: //copy code (c key)
                StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().toString().replaceAll("java.awt.Point", "").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("x", "").replaceAll("y", "").replaceAll(",", ", ")); //get mouse coordinates and set them as a StringSelection
                Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); //get the clipboard
                cb.setContents(ss, ss); //set what is copied to the current mouse coordinates
            break;
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LogManager.getLogManager().reset(); //stop the annoying constant logging of GlobalScreen

        try {
            GlobalScreen.setEventDispatcher(new SwingDispatchService());
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new MainClass());

        jframe(); //Run JFrame code
        check(); //Run check code

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainClass();
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Any help regrading usage of switch statements with JNativeHook is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code solve your problem.

1. I think the main problem is on the `e.getKeyCode()` because it doesn't return the same on `nativeKeyPressed` and `nativeKeyReleased` So I put your code in the method `public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e)`
2. Also I put some comments to visually indicates which key you are pressing.
3. To avoid the "magic numbers" (27, 87, 67 who can guees what does means?) I convert to its string form, I think the code readability is improved.
4. I put the `break;` instruction at the end of each case block, if you don't put the code will be passing through all the cases.

   ```
   public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
       String keyText = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
       switch(keyText){
       case "Escape": //close code (esc key)
           System.out.println("Pressed esc");
           System.exit(0);
           break;
       case "P": //pause code (p key)
           System.out.println("Pressed p");
           run = !run;
           check();
           break;
       case "C": //copy code (c key)
           System.out.println("Pressed c");
           StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().toString().replaceAll("java.awt.Point", "").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("x", "").replaceAll("y", "").replaceAll(",", ", ")); //get mouse coordinates and set them as a StringSelection
           Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); //get the clipboard
           cb.setContents(ss, ss); //set what is copied to the current mouse coordinates
           break;
       }
   }

   public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! My program works now, thank you again for your help!